# ZSH: How to set an associative array name and content dynamically?

Tags: zsh

I'm setting my associative array this way:

```
$ foo=test
$ set -A $foo "a b" "1 2" "c d" "3 4"
$ for key val in "${(@kv)test}"; do echo "$key -> $val" done
a b -> 1 2
c d -> 3 4
```

How to replace the array content `"a b" "1 2" "c d" "3 4"` by a variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set -A array value1 value2` is the ancient ksh  syntax from the early  80s¹ for defining plain arrays. It's not defining associative arrays and is only supported for compatibility with ksh88.

The `k` and `v` parameter expansion flags only make sense for variables that are associative arrays. For other types of variables including plain arrays, they are simply ignored. So here, `"${(@kv)test}"` is the same as `"${(@)test}"` or `"$test[@]"` and expands to all the elements of the plain array².

To declare an associative array, you'd rather use the modern

```
assoc=(
  'key 1' 'value 1'
  'key 2' 'value 2'
)
```

syntax³ *after having declared `assoc` as an associative array* with:

```
typeset -A assoc
```

With recent versions, now that `typeset` has become a dual keyword / builtin, you can also do both the declaration and assignment at once with:

```
typeset -A assoc=(
  'key 1' 'value 1'
  'key 2' 'value 2'
)
```

Then you can do:

```
printf '"%s" => "%s"\n' "${(@kv)assoc}"
```

Or

```
for k v ("${(@kv)assoc}") print -r -- "$k => $v"
```

Or:

```
for k ("${(@k)assoc}") print -r -- "$k => $assoc[$k]"
```

To loop over its keys and values.

To define an associative arrays whose name is stored in a variable from a list of keys and values, you could use:

```
setassoc() {
  typeset -gA $1; shift
  eval "$1"='( "$@[2,-1]" )'
}
```

```
foo=test
setassoc $foo 'key 1' 'value 1' 'key 2' 'value 2'
```

Or if the list of keys and values are stored in a plain array variable:

```
array=('key 1' 'value 1' 'key 2' 'value 2')
setassoc $foo "$array[@]"
```

Incidentally `set -A` could be used here to avoid `eval` (not that there's anything wrong to use `eval` that way here), but you need to make sure the variable is set as an associative array first:

```
foo=test
typeset -A $foo
set -A $foo "$array[@]"
```

And beware that if ksh emulation is enabled (specifically, if the `ksharrays` option is enabled), it needs to be changed to:

```
set -A $foo -- "$array[@]"
```

---

<sup>¹ David Korn chose `-A` as `set -a` from the Bourne shell was already taken. Also explains why `read -A` is used in ksh93 or zsh to read a line into an array. `bash` doesn't support `set -A` even though it based its array design on that of ksh88 (while `zsh` array design is closer to that of csh than to that of ksh), and chose `read -a` instead of `read -A`. A possible source of confusion is that `typeset -a` is to declare a plain array while `typeset -A` is for associative arrays (both from ksh)</sup>

<sup>² and `for k v` assigns `k` and `v` to the elements of the array in turn which explains the output and why it's in the same order as in the assignment (while for associative arrays, there is no guarantee of order).</sup>

<sup>³ that syntax is actually *from* zsh in 1990 and later made its way to ksh93 (though there, as part of a large variable typing that also includes compound variables) and bash (which didn't have arrays until 2.0 in 1996), though it's largely inspired by csh (the first shell with arrays from the late 70s) where the syntax is `set array = (foo bar)`</sup>

Comment: In your first example, `echo ${(t)assoc}` returns `array`, not `association`, but `echo ${(k)assoc}` returns keys like if it was an associated array. I'm a bit puzzled about that, array like this seems enough for what I need.

Comment: Thanks for the historical perspective.

Comment: @DevonDahon, see edit. After `array=(a b c)` where `array` is a plain array, `${(k)array}` is the same as `$array` and expands to all the values.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think using `set` is bad? It seems like the safest way to set values in arrays over say `eval` over `typeset`